# QGIS field relation

Tags: qgis

I am trying to get QGIS to relate two different field within the same layer. If a certain selection in the “failure” field is selected I want the “failure score” field to be a certain value ie “failure” ‘imminent/immediate’ then “failure score” is 50. I am using a value map for the “failure” field.

Comment: this one time calculation or ongoing scoring? You can use field calculator with the following formula to add your scores in the second layer: CASE WHEN "failure" IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN "failure" = 'imminent' THEN 50 WHEN "failure" = 'immediate' THEN 100 END

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a go. It’s a onetime calculation.